# Function that prints out the requested index position in a list?

Tags: python-3.x, list

How can i write a python function that prints out the requested index position in a list?

```
def index_position(my_list, index)
index = my_list[index]
for i in index:
    return index
```

Here I expect the argument to print out the index position of an element of a list list when the function is called.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the index of an item in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-in-a-list)

Comment: The code indentation is incorrect. Furthermore, you seem to have a confusion about return statement and for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understand what you mean, but I'll try to explain.

*How can i write a python function that prints out the requested index position in a list?*

This is very easy, you are actually really close to the solution:

```
def index_position(my_list, index):
     a = my_list[index]
     print(a)
```

This will surelly work by printing the element at the given index (unless its out of bounds for the list)

As for this:
*Here I expect the argument to print out the index position of an element of a list list when the function is called.*

I understand that you want something like a getIndexOf method, that returns the index of an element that you are passing, this could be done like this:

```
def index_position(my_list, index):
    counter = 0;
    for i in my_list:
        if(i == index):
            print(counter)
            return
        counter += 1
```

This will print the the element at the position on the list.